# How do i manage resources in Kotlin ? Trying to make the setUp function run only once not before every test

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso

I want to run the setUp function only once, not before every test from the class. I've tried to make the setUp funtion static but i get an error - unresolved reference

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@LargeTest
open class BaseTest {

    @Rule
    val activityRule = ActivityTestRule(HomeActivity::class.java)




Class that inherits Base test class

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@LargeTest
open class HomeScreenWithoutInternet : BaseTest() {


    private lateinit var context: HomeActivity
    @Before
    open fun setUp() {
        context = activityRule.activity  // "Unresolved reference: activityRule"
        val wifiManager = context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
        wifiManager.isWifiEnabled = false
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5)
        assertFalse("There is internet connection available", isConnected(context))
    }
```

Comment: Why not make that part of the specific test? The very definition of `@Before` is to provide a pre-configuration to **all** tests within the class.

Comment: You must reset the state of all associated entities before each test. You must never carry state between tests, otherwise your tests won't be reliable. For this reason, the method annotated with @Before runs before each test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's recommended to keep tests completely independent from one another, there are things you just can't afford re-setting-up.

What you're looking for is `@BeforeClass` (JUnit 4).

https://www.baeldung.com/junit-before-beforeclass-beforeeach-beforeall

Answer (score 1):

You need to use @get:Rule in Kotlin

```
@get:Rule
val activityRule = ActivityTestRule(HomeActivity::class.java)
```